# Entity Framework MVC code first, migration to production server

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've created a project using EF Version 6.0, with settings of AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

Which worked fine, i could able to deploy in production server on first time, It created desire database tables.

Now for second update, I've get script out from migration so that i can able to run in production server. but i tried many Package Manager commands, but it does creating empty .sql files.

My second Migration has name "201601181549424_Version-1.2.0", i used following sequence of steps and commands to generate .sql file.

- Added desire data classes (which will be creating tables in database) and MVC views and controller.
- Run Package Manger Command is "ADD-MIGRATION Version-1.2.0" has created   201601181549424_Version-1.2.0" file in Migration folder
- Than "UPDATE-DATABASE" - has updated local database, check everything works fine.
- Than "UPDATE-DATABASE -Script" - has created empty.sql file. I am looking to get sql file with creation of database tables in sql file.

Can you please help me understand how i can deploy this in production database.

Thanks,

Comment: change the connection string of your web.config to the production database and then run "update-database". That's the easiest way in my opinion

Comment: I would like to keep track of every changes made in database, so i like to run .sql scrip separately

Comment: you could use "update-database -verbose" and then copy the generated sql. I'll see if there's a better approach

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by this way..

Make desire changes to model, (INSERT OR UPDATE MODEL)

1. Add-Migration
2. Update-Database -Script

(Which will create script and can store for QA or production deployment purpose)

3. Update-Database

(Above command will update model in to local database)